# Temporary User in Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

I need to allow restricted access to my system secured by Keycloak.

Is it possible to create **temporary** user (restricted by time or number of logins = 1) with specific role? Or is it better to create user with role and some clean-up jobs that will delete such users? May this job (scheduyler) be running on Keycloak itself? Or any other suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is possible to create temporary user in keycloak with limited login period by setting expiration date on user account.

This can be done by going to keycloak admin console --> User and setting "Account Expiration" date in Credentials tab.

For login only once,

Set "Required Actions" for the user to "Update password" and configure Expiration option to be "1". This is make user to reset the password on logging, once changed the account will be deactivated.

Note: I haven't tried this scenario practically.